# I am trying to take screenshots with desktopmagic in Jenkins but BitBlt failed error is given

Tags: python, windows, jenkins, screenshot

So I am running this project on Jenkins using Git and taking screenshots of my physical second monitor using desktopmagic: https://github.com/ludios/Desktopmagic

This is all on Windows and in python.

Now when I run this project locally from PyCharm it works fine and screenshots can be taken, however, when I run this as a build on Jenkins I get this Traceback:

```
[11:04:26][Step 1/1]     saveRectToBmp('tmp/screenshot.png', rect=(0, -720, 1280, 0))
[11:04:26][Step 1/1]   File "c:\program files (x86)\python\python27\lib\site-packages\desktopmagic\screengrab_win32.py", line 459, in saveRectToBmp
[11:04:26][Step 1/1]     dc, bitmap = getDCAndBitMap(bmpFilename, rect)
[11:04:26][Step 1/1]   File "c:\program files (x86)\python\python27\lib\site-packages\desktopmagic\screengrab_win32.py", line 240, in getDCAndBitMap
[11:04:26][Step 1/1]     "or an active UAC elevation screen. Error was: " + str(e))
[11:04:26][Step 1/1] desktopmagic.screengrab_win32.GrabFailed: Error during BitBlt. Possible reasons: locked workstation, no display, or an active UAC elevation screen. Error was: BitBlt failed
[11:04:26][Step 1/1] Process exited with code 1
```

I have looked into the error and made sure that the display is active and screensaver is off too, and no UAC is popped up. Perhaps Jenkins doesn't know or don't have access to the physical monitor?

Also to add on, it's the same on TeamCity as well.

Please any help or input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to wrap this up and for future reference, if anyone comes across this problem then all you need to do is create an admin user by going into command prompt and changing your directory to where Jenkins is: `cd jenkins/location/` and run this command:-

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

This will create another instance of Jenkins with admin control and then you should be able to take screenshots.

Hope this is helpful for anyone running into this problem.